# How do I lengthen a cylinder that is tipped on it's axis?

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, origin, dimensions

I need to lengthen objects that are tipped on their axis. I have tried to use local transform orientation and it doesn't work. [image: example]

Comment: could you please show some screenshots?

Comment: Hello :). If the cylinder has applied rotation, you can use either Edge slide (disabled clamp) or a custom orientation :).

Answer (score 4):

You can always move a face along its normal by using the 'Normal' transform orientation.

If combined with the 'Individual Origins' pivot point, many face-islands can be <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> moved along their normals simultaneously:

[image]

(This is not scaling.. any selection of top or bottom faces could be moved just as easily.)

Comment: Oh come on, why didn't I think of this? So obvious now :) (love your new haircut btw)

Comment: Maybe because 'Normal'  and 'Individual Origins' don't always do the lovely things you'd like them to  ..:) On the barnet, (you may have to look up your cockney slang),, Thankyou! It took me _ages_.

Answer (score 2):

Got it. With my cylinder tipped on it's axis:
I moved the cursor to the cylinder to be stretched. In Edit mode I selected both ends of the cylinder, selected the Scale tool, switched the Transformation Orientation to "Normal" and stretched the cylinder with the scale tool lengthwise. That works. Next time I will be more precise with my question. **Thanks all!**[image: Answer]

Answer (score 0):

Try to use dimensions in Transform panel [image]

Comment: I tried that and it distorts the cylinder. I am missing something here.

Comment: My problem I think is trying to do this in Object mode. Sure I can switch to Edit mode and extrude a face but how do I extrude BOTH ends of the cylinder that is at a tipped axis. I am trying to figure out how to orient the scale tool with the cylinders axis.

Comment: This works OK if the mesh is _not_ rotated with respect to its bounding box, (which is oriented along the Object axes).